# How to take a input in python and change the format into txt?

Tags: python, text, format

`This is the whole code`

```
#input from the user
Text = input("Enter a String :) : ")

#this portion will create a file
with open(Text, 'w') as f:
    file = f.write("this is a test file")


#loops through

for i in range(1,100):
#this is creating a new file
    a = open(Text, "a")
    b = a.write("\n this will append to the file")
    a.close() 
    # print(i)

#this portion is reading from the file
f = open(Text, "r")
d = f.read()
print(d,end="")
f.close()
```

`I'm trying to take the input in string, but i want it to save the file in text format`
I'm a beginner, just trying things.

what i want is, that it creates a file in .txt

like,

**input:** `helloWorld`

**output:** `helloWorld.txt`

Comment: Would you mind adding here which part of your code does not work as intended? And what do you mean by "changing the format into binary"?

Comment: not related with opencv

Answer (score 0):

Append ".txt" to the filename the user inputs:

```
#input from the user
Text = input("Enter a String :) : ") + ".txt"
```